# proof involving algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Suppose that $b = 2u$ is even, so that $4u^2 = c^2 - a^2$, where a, b and u are relatively prime. Show that $u^2 = rs$, where $c + a = 2 s$ and $c - a = 2 r$

I have plugged $rs$ into $u^2$ in the equation above, and I have plugged $2s-a$ into $c$ and $c-2r$ into $a$. I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles. Your current title can be applied to nearly every algebra question here.

Comment: Did you intend to write $c$ instead of $b$ in "where a, b, and u are relatively prime"?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$c^2 - a^2 = (c-a)(c+a).$$

If you can show that the two factors on the right are both even then you can divide each by $2$ and show that the numbers you get are relatively prime. Since their product is a square you can conclude that each must be a square.